# Decode result from Buffer.from()

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have following code:

```
Buffer.from([1, 5, 'asd'])
```

Which produces:

```
<Buffer 01 05 00>
```

My question is how can I get my initial data back, in this case:
`[1, 5, 'asd']`

Comment: That `asd` is not in the buffer, so you can't..

Comment: Are you just trying to store simple Javascript objects inside a buffer, and then read back?.  If so, encode -> `b = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify([1, 5, 'asd']))`, and then decode -> `JSON.parse(b)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[buf.toJson()](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_tojson) is something you are looking for, however string `asd` is not valid buffer value.

Buffer stores an array of bytes (int values from `0` to `255`). When `asd` is a string that needs 3 bytes (1 for each letter). In other words string is also an array of bytes.

```
const buf = Buffer.from([1, 5, 'asd'])
const debuf = buf.toJson().data // output: [1,5,0]
```